# Blazor Dropdown with Search field - Handle Onfocusout

Tags: c#, html, twitter-bootstrap, blazor

I have a dropdown with a search field to filter the list. Here is the basic structure:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropdown-button dropdown-toggle" @onclick="e => this.show = !this.show"></button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu @(show ? "show" : "")">
        <input class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="type filter..."/>
        <div class="scrollable-menu">
            <table>
                ...
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I hide the dropdown when the user clicks somewhere else?
If I use the *onblur* event of the button the dropdown gets hidden when the user clicks inside the filter input --> doesnt work.
The dropdown-menu is outside the dropdown div so I can't use that.
It would be ideal if I could group the button and the dropdown list together somehow so that the focusout event only gets triggered when the user clicks outside this "group" of elements.

**EDIT**

I updated the code snipped to show where how I toggle the dropdown.
The `show` variable is also inverted when the user selects an element in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use CSS - hide the `scrollable-menu` by default, then display it when anything in the `dropdown` has focus.

```
.scrollable-menu {
  display: none;
}
.dropdown:focus-within .scrollable-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

Edit: Add more complicated Blazor event based version

This problem (which I had not understood fully before) is usually solved in javascript detecting whether the target element of a focus change is within the container, but that then means interop calls to set/update your show field.

A purely Blazor solution could be handled by delaying the hide and cancelling if focus remains inside.

```html
<div class="dropdown">       
    <button class="dropdown-button dropdown-toggle" @onclick=HandleClick @onfocus=HandleFocus @onblur=HandleBlur ></button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu @(show ? "show" : "")" @onfocusin=HandleFocus @onfocusout=HandleBlur tabindex="-1">
        <input class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="type filter..."/>
        <div class="scrollable-menu">
            <table>
                ...
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```cs
@code{
    bool show;
    CancellationTokenSource tokenSource;
    void HandleClick() => show = !show;
    async Task HandleBlur(FocusEventArgs a)
    {
        tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(async ()=> {
            await Task.Delay(100);
            show = false;
            await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        },tokenSource.Token);
    }        
    void HandleFocus(FocusEventArgs a)
    {
        if (tokenSource is CancellationTokenSource)
            tokenSource.Cancel();
    }        
}
```

Try it out here: https://blazorrepl.com/repl/wFESlpaa33iocZJR52

Comment: That got me really close. The only issue is that I can not close the dropdown anymore by clicking the button again. The show is handled by a variable `@(show ? "show" : "")"`. This variable is triggered by either clicking the button or selecting an element. As the focus is still within the dropdown when clicking the button the `display: block` overrides the show variable I think

Comment: Where do you apply the show class? Could you add it to your question?

Comment: Oh, I didn't read your question properly - updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

use `InvokeVoidAsync`. It will not work if you make it async.

```
@onclick="@(e => {
    JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("eval",$"bootstrap.Dropdown(yourID).toggle()");
})"
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. While this snippet may answer the question, it is better to include some explanation so that the PO and future users understand how it works.